# Getting a "no step-definition method match found for: @setup" in karate with retryScenario

Tags: karate

I'm using `@setup` scenario to create a list of examples which is used in Scenario Outline.
Feature file looks like below.

The test will fail first time as value is 2.

```
Feature: Test Sample

  Background:

  @setup
  Scenario: Setup
    * print 'Setup'
    * def examples = [{value:2},{value:1}]


  @tag1
  Scenario Outline: Scenario
    * print "Scenario <value>"
    * match value == 1

    @tag2=1367591
    Examples:
      | karate.setupOnce().examples |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRXPP.png)

In my junit runner class, I have the following line of code to run the test

```
Results results = Karate.run("classpath:examples").parallel(2);
```

Then I use the following code to retry the failed scenarios

```
for (ScenarioResult scenarioResult : results.getScenarioResults().collect(Collectors.toList())) {
    if (scenarioResult.isFailed()) {
        ScenarioResult retryScenarioResult = results.getSuite().retryScenario(scenarioResult.getScenario());
        results = results.getSuite().updateResults(retryScenarioResult);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
09:42:18.953 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:examples/features/SampleTest.feature:19
* @setup
no step-definition method match found for: @setup
classpath:examples/features/SampleTest.feature:19
```

NOTE: I'm using karate 1.3.1 version

This happens only when the first row in example in setup fails. For the other rows, it work as expected.
I.e the sceanrio is re-executed with the correct row data from examples
I tried with karate.setup() and karate.setupOnce()

Comment: sorry this sounds like a super-edge case that karate possibly does not support. my suggestion is you provide a way to replicate following this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and that `no step-definition method match` sounds really strange to me. even after that I personally don't consider fixing this a priority - so my recommendation is please consider diving into the code and contributing (or please convince someone in your team to)

Comment: an update, we got a PR that seems to fix this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2334 - would be great if you can test the `develop` version, comment on the issue and I can give you instructions

Answer (score 0):

We also ran into this error. I created an issue to track it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2334

Until this is fixed, you can workaround the issue by changing

```java
ScenarioResult retryScenarioResult = results.getSuite().retryScenario(scenarioResult.getScenario());
```

to

```java
Scenario failedScenario = scenarioResult.getScenario();
failedScenario.setSteps(failedScenario.getSteps().stream().filter(s -> s.getIndex() != -1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
ScenarioResult retryScenarioResult = results.getSuite().retryScenario(failedScenario);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I'll try the workaround